# Order in where in

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, where-clause

I have this:

```
select CODART as 'MODELO / REF', DESCLIN as DESCRIPCION, UNIDADES as CANTIDAD 
from LINEPEDI 
where IDPEDV in ('69782','69780','68931','69781')
```

In the result I would like it to return me in the order I have put it but by default it returns it sorted by id.

Would anyone know how to tell him not to order it by id?

Comment: Have you considered using an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They can also result in some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Yes I have tried but I don't know the sentence I have to use with the order by.

It would have to be order by position or something like that but I don't know if that is possible.

And thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort rows in the result set you need to use `ORDER BY`. Otherwise the engine is free to return them with any ordering.

You can do:

```
select
  CODART as "MODELO / REF", 
  DESCLIN as DESCRIPCION, 
  UNIDADES as CANTIDAD 
from LINEPEDI 
where IDPEDV in ('69782','69780','68931','69781')
order by case IDPEDV when '69782' then 1
                     when '69780' then 2
                     when '68931' then 3
                     when '69781' then 4
         end
```

Answer (score 2):

It *might* be easier to use something like a table variable here, with an `IDENTITY`:

```
DECLARE @IDPEDV AS table (ID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
                          IDPEDV varchar(5));
INSERT INTO @IDPEDV (IDPEDV)
VALUES ('69782'),
       ('69780'),
       ('68931'),
       ('69781');

SELECT CODART AS [MODELO / REF],
       DESCLIN AS DESCRIPCION,
       UNIDADES AS CANTIDAD
FROM dbo.LINEPEDI L
     JOIN @IDPEDV ON L.IDPEDV = I.IDPEDV
ORDER BY I.ID;
```